# How do I use the Symfony DomCrawler with Laravel's subdomain routing?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, laravel, phpunit

Currently my site is designed to serve up multiple subdomains like this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'site1'.AppHelper::getDomain()), function(){
    Route::get('{state?}/{variant?}', array("uses" => 'Site1Controller@showIndex'));
});

Route::group(array('domain' => 'site2'.AppHelper::getDomain()), function(){
    Route::get('{state?}/{variant?}', array("uses" => 'Site2Controller@showIndex'));
});

Route::group(array('domain' => 'site3'.AppHelper::getDomain()), function(){
    Route::get('{state?}/{variant?}', array("uses" => 'Site3Controller@showIndex'));
});
```

Now I want to write some tests that crawl these pages checking for specific content. Unfortunately, the only [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#testing-configuration) I can find on the Symfony DomCrawler for subdomains tells me to do this (let's say this is on line 312 of my test):

```
$crawler = $this->$client->request('GET', '/', array(), array(), array(
        'HTTP_HOST'       => 'site1.domain.dev',
        'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Symfony/2.0',
    ));
```

Unfortunately when I run PHPUnit and it gets to this test I see this:

```
1) SiteTest::testSite1ForContent
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:

/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1429
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1050
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1014
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:576
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:597
/var/www/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
/var/www/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:339
/var/www/app/tests/SiteTest.php:312
```

So what is it that I'm not understanding here? The site1.domain.dev definitely resolves normally and has no issues that I can see. It seems to be a problem specific to trying to force the header for the subdomain.

Even apart from a solution, how do I debug this properly? I want to figure out why it's not working/where it's failing since this is my first attempt at writing tests.

Comment: I don't get it. You have subdomains bulit by willcard? Why don't you set second parameter fixed `http://site1.domain.dev/` instead of `/`?

Comment: Well, the subdomains are declared (site1, site2, site3) as the route group and the {state?}/{variant?} part of the actual route is to handle things like site1.domain.dev/TX/a meaning it's the site1 site localized to Texas and using the A variant of the site (A/B testing). As far as I can tell those aren't an issue since they're both optional. Going to site1.domain.dev/ would still match that pattern and does when accessed manually. Just an issue when trying to create a DomCrawler

Comment: In re-reading your comment it seems like you were talking about the actual DomCrawler. I had previously tried defining it as `$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', http://site1.domain.dev/');` but that gives me the same error. I don't understand why that would be though.

Comment: and are you sure that you want to make this by `$this->$client`? Are you keeping object name in variable?

Comment: You may have caught a typo I later took out. This seems to be a problem specific to subdomain groups in Laravel. If I instead use `$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');` and create a non-group based route closure the test works perfectly and can be crawled. It only has trouble resolving against the subdomain. This might be something I have to go to the Laravel IRC for but I'll keep trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started a blank project that just tried to handle this with subdomain routes and it worked perfectly. I realized the issue had to be with what I wrote.

Turns out the issue was actually with a helper I wrote to retrieve the domain. It was trying to access $_SERVER vars that weren't available to the tests when running. Having that return a dev domain if it couldn't retrieve the values solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public function refreshApplication() 
{
    parent::refreshApplication();

    $this->client = $this->createClient(
        array('HTTP_HOST' => 'site1.domain.dev'));
}

public function testSomething()
{
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/something');
}
```